# Exception occur on executing phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

all my xaml page works fine but when i put this below code it gives an error

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton 
            IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/back.png" Text="Previous Point"
               Click="prevPointButton_Click"      />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton 
            IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/minus.png" Text="Zoom In"
                Click="mapZoomMinus"      />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton 
            IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Add.png" Text="Zoom Out"
                 Click="mapZoomPlus"     />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton 
            IconUri="/Assets/AppBar/next.png" Text="Next Point" Click="nextPointButton_Click"
                     />

    </shell:ApplicationBar>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

it doesnot gives the exception detail but this only

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: @Rehan Are you define all event handler in code behind such as Click="mapZoomPlus" ???

Comment: I tried adding your buttons in my solution and there are no such exceptions

Comment: delete the --> at the end

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgotten to remove **-->**  at the end